# How to find the PPA of the Skype package?

Tags: ppa, skype

For example, with a webpage like this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype, how can I find out to which ppa this package belongs? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype isn't part of a ppa, it's part of an official repo. Usually to view info about a package you'll be in the sub page of a ppa, however for this you aren't as skype is just part of the partner repo, and isn't in a ppa.

Comment: how can i find out the repo given the page mentioned in the question? It's looks quite complicated. Thanks!

Comment: Look under the component section at the top left.

Answer (score 1):

Normally all packages that are included in launchpad.net/ubuntu/ are actually inside the default repository! So no need to add a PPA for Skype, just make sure that the partner repository is enabled and you can just search for it in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Just a quick tip: When looking for software it is probably best to only use a PPA if there really isn't another way. Also make sure you only add PPA's that you absolutely trust or are maintained by the developer of the software. A bad PPA can cause all kinds of nasty, hard to troubleshoot issues.